# Deleting (intrusive?) Facebook files ok?

Tags: ios, command-line, macos, facebook

**Platform(s)**: MacOS Catalina (10.15.2) and an iPad (13.3).

**Disclaimer:** I'm in no way experienced or knowledgeable in anything relating to computers.

**Background:** I'm keen to cut ties with Facebook completely and thought I'd investigate if there are any Facebook files lurking around on my Mac to do whatever Facebook files likes to do; spying, stealing info etc.

**Found:** I found the following files using Double Commander, scouring the entire drive.

```
/System/iOSSupport/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/FacebookSettings.axbundle
/System/iOSSupport/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/FacebookSettings.axbundle/Contents/MacOS/FacebookSettings
/System/Library/Accounts/Access/FacebookAccessPlugin.bundle
/System/Library/Accounts/Access/FacebookAccessPlugin.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FacebookAccessPlugin
/System/Library/Accounts/Authentication/FacebookAuthenticationPlugin.bundle
/System/Library/Accounts/Authentication/FacebookAuthenticationPlugin.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FacebookAuthenticationPlugin
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CalendarDraw.framework/Versions/A/Resources/FacebookIcon.tiff
/System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/profile-photo-facebook@2x.png
/System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/badge-facebook@2x.png
/System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/badge-facebook.png
/System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/profile-photo-facebook.png
/System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.facebook.xpc
/System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.facebook.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.facebook
/System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.facebook.xpc/Contents/Resources/FacebookContactUpdater
/System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.facebook.xpc/Contents/Resources/FacebookIcon.icns
/System/Applications/News.app/Contents/Resources/facebook.js
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/idontthinkso/Library/Caches/Firefox/Profiles/8joe3ovp.default-release/safebrowsing/social-tracking-protection-facebook-digest256.vlpset
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/idontthinkso/Library/Caches/Firefox/Profiles/8joe3ovp.default-release/safebrowsing/social-tracking-protection-facebook-digest256.sbstore
```

**Question:** Are these all safe to delete?

**Bonus question!:** Is there a Terminal command to delete files in this manner? As there is for xCode etc.

Comment: TBH/ deleting these files will do nothing. Just don't visit Facebook in a browser.

Comment: @IconDaemon or do so in private mode :P. Apps are no good either. I cant even block ads on app.

Comment: Well, I can’t delete them anyway. Can’t even change permission on their subdirectories. :[

Comment: @nistan123 yes most of the directories listed are fairly important to be able delete directly.

Answer (score 1):

While I am not aware of the insides in detail, but I can comment(answer) on some.

```
/System/iOSSupport/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/FacebookSettings.axbundle
/System/iOSSupport/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/FacebookSettings.axbundle/Contents/MacOS/FacebookSettings
```

- https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=http://www.duozy.com/article/44379.html&prev=search
- http://yesanotheriphoneblog.blogspot.com/p/apple-apps-removal-list-60.html

  indicate that these should be deleted from an iPhone after jailbreaking or otherwise to delete Facebook app from the iPhone. No comment on macOS there. However, I don't even have this(FacebookSettings.axbundle) on my Mac and never had FB on iPhone either.

```
/System/Library/Accounts/Access/FacebookAccessPlugin.bundle
/System/Library/Accounts/Access/FacebookAccessPlugin.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FacebookAccessPlugin
```

- https://opensource.apple.com/source/kext_tools/kext_tools-326.1.12/systempaths.plist.auto.html

  lists them for some reason.

All the tiff, png, icns files are just images and icons and I wouldn't mind them sitting where they are.

For the news one, it's a JavaScript file and it can be worth reading, if it's readable, to see what it has.

For the last two of Firefox, I routinely delete the Profiles folder every time YouTube's suggestions become obsolete or one sided. So you can delete that folder using Finder (yay!) and see if it comes up again. It could be a good thing to save to protect you from tracking!

Answer (score 1):

All the ones in /System are Apple system files that handle integrating MacOS with FaceBook, rather than 'software' written by FaceBook. They certainly aren't going to steal any info from your Mac.

If you don't have a FaceBook account, then they will be unused (like many other system components that you're probably not using).

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for your responses. As mentioned I can't delete any of these files no matter what I do, so I guess a clean reinstall of the OS will solve it - as long as I steer clear from using Facebook whatsoever and perhaps conducting a clean OS reinstall of iPhone and iPad too avoiding the FB app.

Comment: No, a clean install will not change the content of /System (or, to be correct, will just reinstall it).

Comment: You mean, Apple has pre-installed Facebook directories on a completely clean/untouched drive?

Comment: As others have written in their answers/comments: this are support files used *if* you access Facebook (e.g. Accessibility support, login support etc). As long as you don‘t have an FB account (or don‘t access FB from your Mac) nothing will happen.

Comment: and the last two files listed seem so be Settings for a tracking protection function within Firefox, something you probably want to have.

Comment: But that’s exactly what I wrote in my comment. I’ll do a clean reinstall + avoid using FB whatsoever. And i’m downvoted for this for some reason.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "a clean reinstall will solve this" then. A reinstall will install those files again, so what exactly will you gain?

Comment: I wrote ”a clean reinstall will solve this AS LONG as I” avoid logging in to Facebook again. 

The subdirectories in question will appear if I access facebook. Right? So, if I do a clean reinstall of the latest OS these subdirectories should disappear, and won’t reappear as long as I don’t access Facebook whatsoever. Right? 

So, as I wrote in my downvoted post, solution = reinstall OS so subdirectories disappear and thne avoid using facebook so they won’t reappear. Voila! ;)

Comment: Your base assumption is wrong (which probably also explains the downvote): the subdirectories in question will appear if/when you install macOS (the whole content of `/System` is part of a default installation), there is no direct relation to actually using FB.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood you. So, the facebook subdirectories are then preinstalled on a new Mac... Then I’ve learned something new.

Comment: Yes, they are. The code within is used *when* you access FB. Look into `/System/Library/Accounts/Access/` for instance, you will also find stuff for LinkedIn and Weibo.